# How to add textures to PyOpenGL VBOs?

Tags: python, glfw, pyopengl

I am making a 3d game in python, using glfw and pyopengl. I am facing some issues rendering vbos with textures. Let's say I have a 32x32 texture at assets/textures/block/bricks.png. Also, how can I work with multiple textures on a single VBO?

##### main.py

```
# imports
import random
import glfw
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *

# internal imports
from renderer import *

if not glfw.init():
    raise Exception("glfw can not be initialized!")

window = glfw.create_window(800, 500, "PyCraft", None, None)
glfw.make_context_current(window)
renderer = TerrainRenderer(window)

glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)

for i in range(-10, 10):
    for j in range(-10, 10):
        x = i
        y = random.randint(-1, 1)
        z = j
        renderer.add_cube((x, y, z))

camrot = [0, 0]
campos = [0, 0, 0]

# get window size
def get_window_size():
    width, height = glfw.get_window_size(window)
    return width, height

def _setup_3d():
    w, h = get_window_size()

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
    glLoadIdentity()
    gluPerspective(70, w / h, 0.1, 1000)
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
    glLoadIdentity()

def update_on_resize():
    _setup_3d()
    glViewport(0, 0, *get_window_size())

# mainloop
while not glfw.window_should_close(window):
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)

    update_on_resize()

    _setup_3d()
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
    glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0)

    # First person camera translation and rotation
    glRotatef(camrot[0], 1, 0, 0)
    glRotatef(camrot[1], 0, 1, 0)
    glTranslatef(-campos[0], -campos[1], -campos[2])

    # keyboard input
    if glfw.get_key(window, glfw.KEY_ESCAPE) == glfw.PRESS:
        glfw.set_window_should_close(window, True)
    # wasd movement
    if glfw.get_key(window, glfw.KEY_W) == glfw.PRESS:
        campos[2] -= 0.1
    if glfw.get_key(window, glfw.KEY_S) == glfw.PRESS:
        campos[2] += 0.1
    if glfw.get_key(window, glfw.KEY_A) == glfw.PRESS:
        campos[0] -= 0.1
    if glfw.get_key(window, glfw.KEY_D) == glfw.PRESS:
        campos[0] += 0.1
    # Space and shift
    if glfw.get_key(window, glfw.KEY_SPACE) == glfw.PRESS:
        campos[1] += 0.1
    if glfw.get_key(window, glfw.KEY_LEFT_SHIFT) == glfw.PRESS:
        campos[1] -= 0.1
    # Arrow keys rotation
    if glfw.get_key(window, glfw.KEY_UP) == glfw.PRESS:
        camrot[0] -= 1
    if glfw.get_key(window, glfw.KEY_DOWN) == glfw.PRESS:
        camrot[0] += 1
    if glfw.get_key(window, glfw.KEY_LEFT) == glfw.PRESS:
        camrot[1] -= 1
    if glfw.get_key(window, glfw.KEY_RIGHT) == glfw.PRESS:
        camrot[1] += 1

    renderer.render()

    glfw.poll_events()
    glfw.swap_buffers(window)

glfw.terminate()
```

##### renderer.py

```
# imports
import glfw
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *
from ctypes import c_float
import numpy
from PIL import Image

glfw.init()

def load_texture(filename):
    texture = glGenTextures(1)
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture)
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT)
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT)
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR)
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR)
    image = Image.open(filename)
    img_data = numpy.array(list(image.getdata()), numpy.uint8)
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, image.width, image.height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, img_data)
    return texture

class TerrainRenderer:
    def __init__(self, window):
        self.window = window

        self.vertices = []
        self.texCoords = []

        self.vbo = glGenBuffers (1)
        glBindBuffer (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.vbo)

        self.tex_coord_vbo = GLuint(0)
        glGenBuffers(1, self.tex_coord_vbo)
        glTexCoordPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, None)
        glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY)

        self.texture = load_texture("assets/textures/block/bricks.png",)

        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)
        glEnable(GL_BLEND)
        glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)
        glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY)

    def render(self):
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)
        glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)
        glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY)

        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, self.texture)
        glColor3f(1, 1, 1)

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.vbo)
        glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, None)
        glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, None)

        glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, len(self.vertices))
        glFlush()

        glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)
        glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY)
        glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)

    def add_cube(self, pos):
        x, y, z = pos
        X, Y, Z = x + 1, y + 1, z + 1

        # add a quad
        self.vertices.extend([
            # top
            x, y, z,
            x, y, Z,
            X, y, Z,
            X, y, z,

            # bottom
            x, Y, z,
            X, Y, z,
            X, Y, Z,
            x, Y, Z,

            # left
            x, y, z,
            x, Y, z,
            x, Y, Z,
            x, y, Z,

            # right
            X, y, z,
            X, y, Z,
            X, Y, Z,
            X, Y, z,

            # front
            x, y, z,
            x, Y, z,
            X, Y, z,
            X, y, z,

            # back
            x, y, Z,
            X, y, Z,
            X, Y, Z,
            x, Y, Z,
        ])

        img_size = 1

        self.texCoords.extend([
            # top
            0, 0,
            0, img_size,
            img_size, img_size,
            img_size, 0,

            # bottom
            0, 0,
            img_size, 0,
            img_size, img_size,
            0, img_size,

            # left
            0, 0,
            0, img_size,
            img_size, img_size,
            img_size, 0,

            # right
            0, 0,
            img_size, 0,
            img_size, img_size,
            0, img_size,

            # front
            0, 0,
            0, img_size,
            img_size, img_size,
            img_size, 0,

            # back
            0, 0,
            img_size, 0,
            img_size, img_size,
            0, img_size,
        ])

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.vbo)
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, len(self.vertices) * 4, (c_float * len(self.vertices))(*self.vertices), GL_STATIC_DRAW)
        glFlush()

        glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)
        glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, None)

        glTexCoordPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, None)
        glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY)
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.tex_coord_vbo)
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, len(self.texCoords) * 4, (c_float * len(self.texCoords))(*self.texCoords), GL_STATIC_DRAW)
        glFlush()
```

## Output

[image: output]

## Expected output:

The same output but with images instead of white color.

Comment: I have tried a TexCoordPointer and updated the question.

Comment: Found this today while searching on GitHub, it could be useful! https://github.com/totex/PyOpenGL_season_02/blob/master/video_09_VAOs.py