# Adding Textures to PyOpenGL VBOs

Tags: python

I wanted to add textures to PyOpenGL VBOs. I just can't get  it right, and it show a white square! I have tried using a TexCoordPointer ad given here: [How to add textures to PyOpenGL VBOs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71173229/how-to-add-textures-to-pyopengl-vbos) but it is not working!

Comment: I see you're a new user. Please be more specific on your question: do some research, add more details!

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer at the same link mentioned earlier, but it shows me some colourful dots instead.

Comment: Please read the user guidelines for StackOverflow, on how to write good questions and answers.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).